# ASWebAuthenticationSession completionHandler not called on Strava Authentication

Tags: ios, swift, strava, aswebauthenticationsession

ASWebAuthenticationSession completionHandler not called on clicking Authorize button in Strava Authentication. below given is my code.(used [Using ASWebAuthenticationSession to connect to Strava account fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870833/using-aswebauthenticationsession-to-connect-to-strava-account-fails) this link to implement.)

```
import AuthenticationServices

class LinkAppsViewController: UIViewController, ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding{

func authenticate()
    {
        let string = self.createWebAuthUrl()
        guard let url = URL(string: string) else { return }

        self.authSession = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: url, callbackURLScheme: "localhost/", completionHandler:
        {
            url, error in

        })

        self.authSession!.presentationContextProvider = self

        self.authSession?.start()
    }

    fileprivate func createWebAuthUrl() -> String
    {
        var url = String.init()

        url.append("https://www.strava.com/oauth/mobile/authorize")
        url.append("?client_id=<client id>")
        url.append("&redirect_uri=http://localhost/exchange_token")
        url.append("&response_type=code")
        url.append("&approval_prompt=force")
        url.append("&grant_type=authorization_code")
        url.append("&scope=activity:write,activity:read_all")

        return url
    }

    func presentationAnchor(for session: ASWebAuthenticationSession) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        print(session)
        return view.window!
    }
}
```

and my info.plist file looks like
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I got it by changing my code like..

```
fileprivate func createWebAuthUrlStrava() -> String
{
    var url = String.init()

    url.append("https://www.strava.com/oauth/mobile/authorize")
    url.append("?client_id=<client id>")
    url.append("&redirect_uri=abcd://localhost/exchange_token")
    url.append("&response_type=code")
    url.append("&approval_prompt=force")
    url.append("&grant_type=authorization_code")
    url.append("&scope=activity:write,activity:read_all")

    return url
}
```

info.plist

[image]

Change `<client id>` with your client id and abcd with your app name..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct in changing the URL Scheme format to `abcd`. However, the value of the `callbackURLScheme` parameter passed when initializing `ASWebAuthenticationSession` must be the same as this URL Scheme(`abcd`). Therefore, your code should be changed as follows:

```swift
self.authSession = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: url, callbackURLScheme: "abcd", completionHandler:
{ url, error in

 })
```

You may also refer to [Apple's official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/authenticating_a_user_through_a_web_service?language=objc) about how to use `ASWebAuthenticationSession`.